# Creating TermDocumentMatrix: issue with number of documents

Tags: r, statistics, nlp, tm, term-document-matrix

I'm attempting to create a term document matrix with a text file that is about 3+ million lines of text. I have created a random sample of the text, which results in about 300,000 lines.

Unfortunately when use the following code I end up with 300,000 documents. I just want 1 document with the frequencies for each bigram:

```
library(RWeka)
library(tm)

corpus <- readLines("myfile")
numberLinesCorpus <- 3000000
corpus_sample <- text_corpus[sample(1:numberLinesCorpus, numberLinesCorpus*.1, replace = FALSE)]
myCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(corpus_sample))
BigramTokenizer <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = 1, max = 2))
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(myCorpus, control = list(tokenize = BigramTokenizer))
```

The sample contains approximately 300,000 lines. However, the number of documents in tdm is also 300,000.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use the `paste` function on your `corpus_sample` vector.

Paste, with a value set for `collapse` takes a vector with many text elements and converts it to a vector with one text elements, where the elements are separated by the string you specify.

```
text <- c('a', 'b', 'c')
text <- paste(text, collapse = " ")
text
# [1] "a b c"
```

Comment: Now I have the following error message: Error in ls(envir = envir, all.names = private) : 
  invalid 'envir' argument
Error during wrapup: cannot open the connection

Comment: Hm, error in ls? That seems strange. Where exactly are you getting the error message? 

If you could rewrite the question with some data to make it reproducible it would be easier to help fix this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I was able to create the DocumentTermMatrix without the tokenizer = Bigram.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `quanteda` package, as an alternative to `tm`.  That will do what you want in the following steps, after you've created `corpus_sample`:

```
require(quanteda)
myDfm <- dfm(corpus_sample, ngrams = 2)
bigramTotals <- colSums(myDfm)
```

I also suspect it will be faster.